# Find the 'RARE' user based on occurrence in two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

This is what my data frame looks like :
its the data of a song portal(like itunes or raaga)

```
datf <- read.csv(text =
"albumid,date_transaction,listened_time_secs,userid,songid
6263,3/28/2017,59,3747,6263
3691,4/24/2017,53,2417,3691
2222,3/24/2017,34,2417,9856
1924,3/16/2017,19,8514,1924
6691,1/1/2017,50,2186,6691
5195,1/1/2017,64,2186,5195
2179,1/1/2017,37,2186,2179
6652,1/11/2017,33,1145,6652")
```

My aim is to pick out the rare user. A 'rare' user is the one which visits the portal not more than once in each calendar month.

for e.g : 2186 is not rare. 2417 is rare because it occurred only once in 2 diff months, so are 3747,1145 and 8514.

I've been trying something like this :

```
DuplicateUsers <- duplicated(songsdata[,2:4])
DuplicateUsers <- songsdata[DuplicateUsers,]


DistinctSongs <- songsdata %>%
  distinct(sessionid, date_transaction, .keep_all = TRUE)

RareUsers <- anti_join(DistinctSongs, DuplicateUsers, by='sessionid')
```

but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `library(dplyr)` you could do this:

```
# make a new monthid variable to group_by() with
songdata$month_id <- gsub("\\/.*", "", songdata$date_transaction)

RareUsers <- group_by(songdata, userid, month_id) %>%
    filter(n() == 1)

RareUsers
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   userid, month_id [5]
  albumid date_transaction listened_time_secs userid songid month_id
    <int>            <chr>              <int>  <int>  <int>    <chr>
1    6263        3/28/2017                 59   3747   6263        3
2    3691        4/24/2017                 53   2417   3691        4
3    2222        3/24/2017                 34   2417   9856        3
4    1924        3/16/2017                 19   8514   1924        3
5    6652        1/11/2017                 33   1145   6652        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
df %>%
  mutate(mth = lubridate::month(mdy(date_transaction))) %>%
  group_by(mth, userid) %>%
  filter(n() == 1)
```

which gives:

```
  albumid date_transaction listened_time_secs userid songid   mth
    <int>           <fctr>              <int>  <int>  <int> <dbl>
1    6263        3/28/2017                 59   3747   6263     3
2    3691        4/24/2017                 53   2417   3691     4
3    2222        3/24/2017                 34   2417   9856     3
4    1924        3/16/2017                 19   8514   1924     3
5    6652        1/11/2017                 33   1145   6652     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with base R:

```
# parse date and extract month
datf$date_transaction <- as.Date(datf$date_transaction, "%m/%d/%Y")
datf$month <- format(datf$date_transaction, "%m")

# find non-duplicated pairs of userid and month
aux <- datf[, c("userid", "month")]
RareUsers <- setdiff(aux, aux[duplicated(aux), ])
RareUsers
#   userid month
# 1   3747    03
# 2   2417    04
# 3   2417    03
# 4   8514    03
# 5   1145    01
```

If you need the other columns:

```
merge(RareUsers, datf)
#   userid month albumid date_transaction listened_time_secs songid
# 1   1145    01    6652       2017-01-11                 33   6652
# 2   2417    03    2222       2017-03-24                 34   9856
# 3   2417    04    3691       2017-04-24                 53   3691
# 4   3747    03    6263       2017-03-28                 59   6263
# 5   8514    03    1924       2017-03-16                 19   1924
```